# angular2 pipe Template parse error

Tags: angular, filter, angularjs-filter, pipes-filters, angular2-custom-pipes

i am trying to implement a simple search using pipes. I am really new to the concepts of pipe and angular2, so i need your help

here is my html:

```
<input  type="textarea"  placeholder="branch" [(ngModel)]="search.branch" name="branch">
 <tr *ngFor="let loan of loans | loanfilter:search.branch ">
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>{{loan.loanId}}</td>
            <td>{{loan.custName}}</td>
            <td>{{loan.vehicleNum}}</td>
            <td>{{loan.TC}}</td>
            <td>{{loan.RE}}</td>
        </tr>
```

loan.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoanService } from '../../services/loans.service';
import { Loan } from '../../../loan';
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { LoanFilterPipe } from '../../pipes/loan.pipe';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'loans',
    templateUrl: './loans.component.html',
    providers: [LoanService],
    declarations: [LoanFilterPipe]  //getting error on this line: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'declarations' does not exist in type 'Component'.
})

export class LoansComponent{

    loans : Loan[];
    custName: any;

    constructor(private loanService: LoanService){
        this.getloans();
    };

    getloans(){
        this.loanService.getLoan()
            .subscribe(loans => {
                this.loans = loans;
                console.log(loans);
            });

    }
};
```

the errors i am getting are:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

loan.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'loanfilter'
})

export class LoanFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(loans: any[], args: any): any{
        return loans.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(args[0].title) !== -1);
    }
}
```

I have also used a module.ts file to declare the pipe and all other components:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { LoansComponent } from './components/loans/loans.component';
import { LoanFilterPipe } from './pipes/loan.pipe';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LoansComponent, LoanFilterPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [LoanFilterPipe]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import `FormsModule` in you app module.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { LoansComponent } from './components/loans/loans.component';
import { LoanFilterPipe } from './pipes/loan.pipe';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LoansComponent, LoanFilterPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [LoanFilterPipe]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: getting a different error now `TypeError: Cannot read property 'branch' of undefined`

Comment: you need to define `public search:any={ branch:''}` inside your `LoansComponent`

Comment: getting this error now:  `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: Try to insert `if(!loans || !args) return;` as first line to `transform()` function inside `LoanFilterPipe`

Comment: getting this error : `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `FormsModule` in your code

> because according to angular `FormsModule` is must to add while bootstraping if you are using `ngModel` because as of now ngModel is a part of FormModule

Comment: getting a different error now `TypeError: Cannot read property 'branch' of undefined`

Comment: getting this error now: `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest you have to import `FormsModule`

Also you have set `search.branch` as ngModel which is not declared in the component typescript file.

And also you dont have to give `declarations`  array in component decorator. 
Remove  `declarations: [LoanFilterPipe]` from the @Component.

It is given in the  NgModule.You dont have to put it in export unless you are going to use in another module.

Comment: is my LoanFilterPipe wrong  because i am getting this error `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: no i think that has to do with the async post request. put your ngFor inside a `<div *ngIf="loans">`

Comment: or set `this.loans = [];` in component constructor

Comment: oh my god!!1 these errors keep on coming `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: is it because of my array gets overrided for each iteration

Comment: `item.title` is null. I guess loan title is not set and you have to put a null check. "1 these errors keep on coming" > that is part of programming :)..

Comment: where exactly should i null check?

Comment: `return loans.filter(item =>item.title && item.title.indexOf(args[0].title) !== -1);`

Comment: is there any other way to filter or search other than this.